# play a random music from my playlist onclick image

Tags: javascript, audio, onclick, dreamweaver

I have this code that let's one music play when I click on the image (the sound isn't working on the code below but it works on my site) and pause the music when I click it again.

My doubt is, how can I load a random music from my `var sounds` playlist each time someone enters my website and click the image?

Thanks in advance.

```js
<script>
    var sounds = [
 "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/royksopp.mp3",
 "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
 "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
 "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/mosdef.mp3",
 "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/oizo.mp3",
 "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/dilla.mp3",];
 
 function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
        
  var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        if (!audie.src || audie.src !== audioFile) audie.src = audioFile;
        console.log(audie.paused);
        if (audie.paused == false) {
            console.log('pause');
            audie.pause();
        } else {
            console.log('play');
            audie.play();
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<img src="http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogobw.png" onclick="StartOrStop('http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/oizo.mp3')" class="spin" align="left" onmouseover="this.src='http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogocolor.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogobw.png'" onmousedown="this.src='http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogocolor.png'" onmouseup="this.src='http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogobw.png'" width="165px" height="190px" >
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
<script>
    var sounds = [
        "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/royksopp.mp3",
        "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
        "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
        "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/mosdef.mp3",
        "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/oizo.mp3",
        "http://www.vtxfactory.com/sounds/dilla.mp3"
    ];

    function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        if (audie.paused) {
            audie.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
            audie.play();
        } else {
            audie.pause();
        }
    }
</script>

<img src="http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogobw.png" onclick="StartOrStop()" class="spin" align="left" onmouseover="this.src = 'http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogocolor.png'" onmouseout="this.src = 'http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogobw.png'" onmousedown="this.src = 'http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogocolor.png'" onmouseup="this.src = 'http://vtxfactory.com/images/vtxfactorylogobw.png'" width="165px" height="190px" >
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter function just to achieve that.

```
function getRandom ( arr ) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1)) + 0;
  return arr[rand];
}

audie.src = getRandom(sounds);
audie.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the argument from the function StartOrStop and add this as your audio source

`audie.src = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];`